# Saving photos for sharing later in an app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter

Is the following scenario possible on either iOS or Android?

1. User is using an app without any connectivity (they are on a plane)
2. They take a photo
3. The app gives them the option to select that photo and share it via Twitter or FB
4. As the app has no connectivity, can the Tweet or FB share be saved as a "draft" within the app and then when the user has connectivity, they go back into a drafts folder and can share/upload the photo to FB/Twitter?

Thanks

Comment: yeah it can be done, just like when you make email on adnroid and send it without connection to net it will wait in drafts untill you dont get connected and send itself automatiaclly

Comment: I'm iOS for sure yes. The app has to be front most to detect network changes but conceptually this will work. Surely the same for Android.